# Generic Type Inference with ReadOnlySpan in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core, type-inference

I'm trying to create a method that operates on a generic `ReadOnlySpan<T>`, so that I can pass an array or a stack-allocated buffer without changing my code. I also want to restrict the type `T` to only be a value type.

The method looks like this:

```csharp
void Test1<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> foo) where T : struct
{
}
```

However the compiler is not able to infer the type without passing the type argument:

```csharp
Test1(new[] {42}); // Doesn't compile
Test1<int>(new[] {42}); // Compiles
```

I also tried different approaches and I found some interesting behaviors:

```csharp
void Test1<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> foo) where T : struct
{
}

void Test2<T>(T[] foo) where T : struct
{
}

void Test3<T>(T[] foo)
{
}

void Test4<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> foo)
{
}

void Test5<T>(List<T> foo) where T : struct
{
}

void Test6<T>(List<T> foo)
{
}

Test1(new[] {42}); // NO
Test2(new[] {42}); // OK
Test3(new[] {42}); // OK
Test4(new[] {42}); // NO
Test5(new List<int> {42}); // OK
Test6(new List<int> {42}); // OK

Test1<int>(new[] {42}); // OK
Test4<int>(new[] {42}); // OK
```

It seems that the type inference doesn't work properly only with the `*Span`s (arrays and `List`s work correctly), and I guess that the fact that `ReadOnlySpan` are `ref struct` might be the cause of the problem.

What is the real cause of this different behavior?

Is there a way to help the compiler infer the datatype of the `ReadOnlySpan` in `Test1()` method?

**Update:**

I tried declaring explicitly the type of the argument:

```cs
ReadOnlySpan<int> testSpan = new[] {42};
Test1(testSpan); // OK!

Span<int> test = new[] {42};
Test1(test); // NO
```

It seems that the real problem here is the implicit conversion.

Can anyone explain it better?

Comment: Would quotes from the spec satisfy you? If not, please clarify what kind of answer you are looking for.

Comment: The real problem is that C# does not infer arguments based on inner generics, its not that clever. It is how it is.

Comment: @Sweeper: yes please, I'd like to better understand the inner gears of the compiler.

Comment: @freakish: it doesn't seem to be the case: as you can see the inner generic of List is correctly inferred.

Comment: @frasten sorry, what I meant is that combination of generic argument inference and implicit cast is too much for it. I'm not sure you will get a better answer than that here. After all these are internal details of the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's follow the [type inference process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1263-type-inference)!

In the first phase, this case matches:

> if Eᵢ has a type U and the corresponding parameter is a value parameter (§15.6.2.2) then a lower-bound inference is made from U to Tᵢ.

Applying that to this case, that would be "`new[] {42}` has a type `int[]`, then a lower-bound inference is made from `int[]` to `ReadOnlySpan<T>`".

How a lower-bound inference is made is specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#126310-lower-bound-inferences).

> A lower-bound inference from a type U to a type V is made as follows:

Here `U` is `int[]` and `V` is `ReadOnlySpan<T>`, and this step is exactly where things go wrong. Going through the cases, `ReadOnlySpan<T>` is not `T`, it is also not nullable, so we are down to:

> Otherwise, sets U₁...Uₑ and V₁...Vₑ are determined by checking if any of the following cases apply:

This is where it finds "related" generic type parameters and array component types, and makes inferences about them. For example, here's an inference that it can make, in plain language:

> given a `List<Foo>` argument, and a `IEnumerable<T>` parameter, then `T` must be `Foo` or some superclass of it (aka a "lower bound").

U₁...Uₑ in the above case would be `Foo`, and V₁...Vₑ would be `T`.

Unfortunately, none of those cases apply to `int[]` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>`, so no inference is made.

Those cases handles array types (e.g. `int[]` to `T[]`),

> V is an array type V₁[...]and U is an array type U₁[...] of the same rank

the implicit conversion from array types to the collection interfaces (e.g. `int[]` to `IEnumerable<T>`),

> V is one of `IEnumerable<V₁>`, `ICollection<V₁>`, `IReadOnlyList<V₁>`, `IReadOnlyCollection<V₁>` or `IList<V₁>` and U is a single-dimensional array type U₁[]

and the type parameters of generic types that inherit/implement each other (e.g. `Dictionary<string, int>` to `IDictionary<T, U>`).

> V is a constructed class, struct, interface or delegate type C<V₁...Vₑ> and there is a unique type C<U₁...Uₑ> such that U (or, if U is a type parameter, its effective base class or any member of its effective interface set) is identical to, inherits from (directly or indirectly), or implements (directly or indirectly) C<U₁...Uₑ>.

It does not check for any arbitrary implicit conversions like the one from arrays to `ReadOnlySpan<T>`, however.

That said, the language could have been designed so that a special case isadded to the second case above. Adding `ReadOnlySpan<T>`/`Span<T>` to the list of interface, in addition to `IEnumerable<T>` and others. Let's hope that this is implemented in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer and your precious time!